# Regular Perturbation to obtain solution to: $y''+y= \epsilon y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, perturbation-theory

The following perturbation problem:
$y''+ y = \epsilon y^2, y(0,\epsilon)=1, y'(0,\epsilon)=0$

So far I have deduced that:
$y_0''+y_0=0, y_0(0)=1, y_0'(0)=0$, and so $y_0(x)= cos(x)$

For the second term: $y_1''+y_1=y_0^2$ with $y_1(0)=0, y_1'(0)=0$

How is the term $y_2(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}cos(x)-\frac{1}{6}cos(2x)$ deduced if your applying the method of undetermined coefficient.
Unsure of the best particular solution which should be used for the homogenous ODE.

Comment: This is not a question about perturbation theory, just about solving this ODE. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139188/131807. Also it's just another bit of your previous question, which probably doesn't need it's own question.