# $f(x) = \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x+y)f(y)dy$ show that $f$ is of the form $f(x) = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this question. I found the relation $f(x) = -f''(x)$ since:

$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\pi}\sin(x+y)f(y)dy = \int_0^{\pi}\cos(x+y)f(y)dy$

So $f''(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^{\pi}\cos(x+y)f(y)dy = \int_0^{\pi}-\sin(x+y)f(y)dy = -f(x)$.

Though, not sure how to show from here that $f$ is of the form $f(x) = a\cos(x) + b\sin(x)$?

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cos$ and $\sin$ using `\cos` and `\sin`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \int_0^\pi \sin(x+y)f(y)\,dy \\
&= \int_0^\pi (\sin x\cos y + \cos x\sin y)f(y)\,dy \\
&= \left(\int_0^\pi f(y)\sin y \,dy\right)\cos x + \left(\int_0^\pi f(y)\cos y \,dy\right)\sin x.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to prove the statement without necessarily finding the coeffiecients?

Comment: @Aladin Yes, you showed that $f'' = -f$ and it is known that the solutions of the ODE $y''+y=0$ are precisely of the form $y(x) = a\cos x + b \sin x$. For example, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2139188/144766).

Answer (score 0):

$$f''(x) = \int_0^\pi \dfrac{d^2}{dx^2} \sin(x+y) f(y)\; dy = - \int_{0}^\pi \sin(x+y) f(y) \; dy = - f(x)$$
All solutions to this differential equation are of the given form.